# accessing a bean defined in an xml from another xml file in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

In a `Spring web app` I have some common beans such as `dataSource`, `transactionManager`, `mailSender` etc. defined in an xml file. I also have many other xml files which I am using to start some tasks, and I am importing them in here:

servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        p:initialSize="1"
        p:maxWait="30000"
        p:maxIdle="-1"
        p:maxActive="-1" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<import resource="aTaskStarter.xml"/>
```

Now in the `aTaskStarter.xml` file I would like to access those beans and pass them to the java class:

aTaskStarter.xml:

```
<bean id="dailyReportTask" class="com.package.task.MyTask">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should just move up the import to before the bean definitions and all should function as you expect...

The documentation states

> It's often useful to split up container definitions into multiple XML
>   files. One way to then load an application context which is configured
>   from all these XML fragments is to use the application context
>   constructor which takes multiple Resource locations. With a bean
>   factory, a bean definition reader can be used multiple times to read
>   definitions from each file in turn.
>
> Generally, the Spring team prefers the above approach, since it keeps
>   container configurations files unaware of the fact that they are being
>   combined with others. However, an alternate approach is to from one
>   XML bean definition file, use one or more instances of the import
>   element to load definitions from one or more other files. Any import
>   elements must be placed before bean elements in the file doing the
>   importing. Let's look at a sample:

```
<beans>

  <import resource="services.xml"/>

  <import resource="resources/messageSource.xml"/>

  <import resource="/resources/themeSource.xml"/>

  <bean id="bean1" class="..."/>

  <bean id="bean2" class="..."/>
  . . .
```

> In this example, external bean definitions are being loaded from 3
>   files, services.xml, messageSource.xml, and themeSource.xml. All
>   location paths are considered relative to the definition file doing
>   the importing, so services.xml in this case must be in the same
>   directory or classpath location as the file doing the importing, while
>   messageSource.xml and themeSource.xml must be in a resources location
>   below the location of the importing file. As you can see, a leading
>   slash is actually ignored, but given that these are considered
>   relative paths, it is probably better form not to use the slash at
>   all.
>
> The contents of the files being imported must be fully valid XML bean
>   definition files according to the DTD, including the top level beans
>   element.

Answer (score 0):

put the common stuff in a third xml file and include it in the other two files:

```
<import resource="common.xml" />
```